# Доказательство ортогональности подпространству

Tags: математика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данную задачу. Пытался читать Колмогорова, но не нашёл путей для доказательства данной проблемы.

Comment: Я нашел поистине удивительное доказательство этого утверждения, но отсутствие математических формул на RuSO не позволяет привести его здесь... :)

Comment: Это  не домашка, это математика, т.е. совершеннейший оффтоп на сайте по программированию.

Answer (score 2):

Для доказательства ортогональности

- Докажите сначала, что

  *< x - P<sub>H<sub>0</sub></sub>(x), e<sub>i</sub> > = 0*, для любого *i*

  Это доказывается из определения *P<sub>H<sub>0</sub></sub>(x)*, свойств скалярного произведения

  *< a + b, c > = < a, c > + < b, c >*
      *< Ca, b > = C< a, b >*

  и ортонормированности системы *(e<sub>i</sub>)*, т.е. того факта, что

  *< e<sub>i</sub>, e<sub>j</sub> > = 0|1*, в зависимости от выполнения равенства *i=j*
- Из этого доказывается требуемое утверждение для произвольного вектора *y* из *H<sub>0</sub>*, т.к. вектор *y* является линейной комбинацией векторов из *(e<sub>i</sub>)*

Самосопряженность вообще доказывается в лоб путем записи выражения для *< P<sub>H<sub>0</sub></sub>(x), y >* и перегруппировки слагаемых/множителей в нем по тем же свойствам скалярного произведения. То есть можно в два-три шага показать что

*< P<sub>H<sub>0</sub></sub>(x), y >* = ∑ < e<sub>i</sub>, x > < e<sub>i</sub>, y >

Выражение справа совершенно симметрично по отношению к *x* и *y*.